# Android app, how to store information to internet and other people can see?

Tags: android

I've done Android development before (junior level obviously), now trying something different. 
I just want to know how to store information to internet and other people can see? I guess it is not SQLite etc, please point me a right direction so I could follow.

I mean it is an app, whoever has it on his phone can input some information and other people who have downloaded and installed it can see the information submitted. 
For a website, obviously the host will provide the storage but how about an Android app?

Thanks!

Comment: You are in the wrong place for this kind of question. You should really google about it first, have some knowledge, then ask here if there is something specific you'd like know.

Comment: Well, I really dislike replies like yours. Google is there, yes, but this site exists for reasons. One of them is kindly answering the questions (if they matter to Information Technology, of course) rather then telling ops go seek help from Google.

Comment: For mobile you have to call web service to get the updated data from server and store them in your database if you want to see in offline mode.

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you, but StackOverflow is a community where many developers come together and share their knowledge to help others **for free**. The question you are asking is too broad and pages of writing would not be sufficient to you to start working on an area you are not experienced with. So, I am repeating what I said. This is the place where you ask specific questions which has specific answers. This is the way to use this community. You really should take a look at the Help section, especially this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Welcome to the community.

Comment: restful api may help you

Comment: @Mergo, I posted my answer to your question, after you editted your post. Don't need to be angry, I was just trying to help you prepare better questions for your next time. Well prepared questions always get better answers, here.

Answer (score 0):

After your last edit, I see your point. (Before that it wasn't clear what you were asking exactly)

For storing information -- that can be on file, database, webpage, etc. -- you obviously need a place to store your data. You're right. With website hosting you mostly get a database with it and that can be used to store information. That is the same with an android (or any native app). If your host is providing a database or cloud storage seperately, you may choose that option. In order to use that place, you should setup your host's server's IP address in order to reach it over the internet. In order to reach your database remotely, you can use your platforms native tools.

But if you want to create multiple clients (like client apps for ios, android, windows, windows phone, etc...) you need to create a Restful API to serve your data and that API should be hosted in the cloud. Then your native applications can use this Restful API you created and get the data from your database through it. That API will be the bridge between you native apps and database and you can configure your data manipulations and security (Access Tokens using Bearer Token Headers) on that API.

Does that answer your question?

P.S. Sorry if I offended you with my comments, but it's not the duty of moderators to warn and improve first messages of new comers. When you take a look at the [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

A client/server architecture is what you're looking for.
In order to have unique information reachable by all users, you have to provide a web-service linked to a database on your server that the client app (the android app) will query via the Internet.
There are many ways to implement such architecture, but I would recommend you to learn about REST web services, Java EE, etc...